# DIY door stopper

Tags: door

I have bought several door stops for my door but every door stop passes under the door gap because it is too high. 
I was wondering whether I could make a door stop myself out of everyday materials/objects to prevent it from opening completely and smashing a mirror that is behind it.

Any ideas?

Comment: A picture of the actual setup would work well for this, so we can advise on alternative mounting options for your existing stop or alternative solutions if the room layout is really awkward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple DIY idea that has the potential to look good is to make a stuffed animal / plushy into a door stopper.

You need to select a plushy that is higher than the door gap and wider than the door handle. Something with a broad base works very well, like an owl, penguin, duck or anything in a rather spherical form. You could also use a small pillow if the aesthetics of a stuffed animal don't appeal to you.

Cut the seam at the bottom of the plushy just wide enough open to remove half of the filling. Then insert a plastic bag in the middle of the remaining filling and fill it with dry sand or pebbles. Securily close or tie the bag and set the plushy on the ground where it can stop the door.

The sand or stones will give it enough weight and structure to stop the door, while the remaining filling will keep the door and wall intact.

Comment: That's an excellent idea!

Answer (score 2):

All the answers were really good but I'm posting here to tell you what I finally did.

I took 2 door stoppers that I had previously bought and were too short for the door and tied them together with duct tape! It works like a charm now! :)

Answer (score 1):

A an effective door stop need not be a permanent thing.

My first thought is not attractive but may give you some ideas.

A plastic two-litre carbonated drink container is light and very tough. You can decorate it or cover it with something to appear more attractive. You may want to leave it as is… to use as a conversation starter.

You can hang an empty one from the door knob to prevent the open door from striking the wall-mounted mirror behind it.

Alternately, you can put a full "door stop" on the floor behind the door. You would want to fill a clean empty plastic two-litre carbonated drink container and screw the top on securely.

Place a door stop as far from the hinges as possible close to the furthest edge of the door to prevent "springing" the hinges loose from simple leverage.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

2 ideas that I have used. 
A box or bucket used to store umbrellas. 
An gallon of paint. Bonus is easy to reposition to hold the door open.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'pool noodles'. These can also be used when the door is closed to seal the entire door bottom so heat doesn't leak through the gap.

[https://www.amazon.com/Oodles-Noodles-Deluxe-Foam-Pool/dp/B01L094C62](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01L094C62)

Answer (score 0):

If you install the door stop **on the door** near the bottom, it pushes against the wall to stop the door. In effect, you **reverse the usual setup** where the doorstop is fixed to the wall.

If you can reuse your parts, there is nothing more to buy or make.

You will want to place a small floor tile (or something similar) where the stop reaches the wall to prevent damage.